# Perform multiple math operations on columns in df

Tags: pandas

I want to do operation [(b-a)/a] * 100 on a dataframe [i.e., percentage change from a reference value]. where a is my first column and b is all other columns of the dataframe.
I tried below steps and it is working but very messy !!

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'obj1': [1, 3, 4],
                   'obj2': [6, 9, 10], 'obj3':[2, 6, 8]},
                  index=['circle', 'triangle', 'rectangle'])

#first we subtract all columns with first col - as that is the starting point : b-a

df_aftersub = df.sub(pd.Series(df.iloc[:,[0]].squeeze()),axis='index')

#second we divide the result with first column to get change - b-a/a

df_change = df_aftersub.div(pd.Series(df.iloc[:,[0]].squeeze()),axis='index')

#third we multiply with 100 to get percent change - b-a/a*100

df_final = df_change*100

df_final
```

output needed

```
            obj1 obj2   obj3
circle      0.0 500.0   100.0
triangle    0.0 200.0   100.0
rectangle   0.0 150.0   100.0
```

how to do it in less lines of code and if possible less temporary dataframes (if possible simple to understand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First subtract first column by [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html) and divide by [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html), last multiple by `100`:

```
s = df.iloc[:, 0]
df_final = df.sub(s, axis=0).div(s, axis=0).mul(100)
print (df_final)
           obj1   obj2   obj3
circle      0.0  500.0  100.0
triangle    0.0  200.0  100.0
rectangle   0.0  150.0  100.0
```

Comment: this works for the second column. for the third column onwards its différant. as i always want to measure pct_change from the first column (not the previous column). is there an option.

Comment: @pranavnerurkar - Not sure if understand, second column is count by percent change by previous, first column. Is possible change data sample for see how this solution failed?

Comment: i have added desired output. if i try your code, second column is correct but third column (onwards) result is different. what i should get is 100 in all rows of third column. by your method i get -66,-33,-20 in third column.

Comment: it is pct_change from first column that i need (not previous column)